# Minor typesetting issue. Special L character

Tags: symbols, typography

I need to write this:

[image: Special L character]

How do one produce the special L character. I've search the web, be simply can't find anyone asking a similar question.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As said in the comments, I’d suggest to define a command for this. That way it is easy to change the appearance later (macro name taken from Joseph …).

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\laevo{\textsc{l}}

\begin{document}
poly-\laevo-lysine
\end{document}
```

If the font doesn’t have small caps (and only then) one might use a scaled upper case `L` (using `\scalebox` from `graphicx.sty`):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand\laevo{\scalebox{0.75}{L}}

\begin{document}
poly-\laevo-lysine
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 10):

It just looks to me like a smallcaps L. `\textsc{l}` should do it!

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
poly-\textsc{l}-lysine
\end{document}
```

One of the difficulties in starting off with *TeX is just learning what some of its features are called. It's a big world, so plan at least 30 minutes or so sometime soon just to read through a *TeX introduction; it just makes this whole thing that much more fun!

Edit: Make sure to check out Tobi's helpful clarification on fonts without small caps below!

Comment: Note that not all fonts have small caps! In that case (and only in that case) `\scalebox{0.8}{L}` (needs `graphicx.sty`) might help. Anyway it would be a good idea to define macro for that, e.g. `\newcommand\smallL{\textsc{l}}` and then `poly-\smallL-lysine`.

Comment: Good point, thanks! Based on the question I (perhaps incorrectly) assumed OP would be using the default font.

Comment: Your welcome! I guess the OP uses a standard font, but it’s worth mentioning it. You may add this (and the definition of a command) to you answer ;-)

Comment: Richard, Perfect. Thank you, that solved my issue

Comment: @J.Doe, glad to hear it! And Tobi, thanks, but I won't steal your spotlight on a very helpful additon. (And it's good to see another musician on here!)

Comment: @Tobi If going for a defined name, I'd pick `\laevo` here as that is what the"L" means (paired with `\dextro` for "D").

Comment: @Richard: In that case I hope you don’t mind, that I added another answer ;-)

Comment: @JosephWright: Thanks. I had absolutely now idea what it meant B-)